# cannot load dll using ctypes.open()

Tags: c, firefox, dll, firefox-addon, jsctypes

I have some dll i'm not able to load using ctypes.open() method.
I have no clue why. It has C extern functions, all other dlls from the same path are loaded correctly.

In FF 8 the dll is loaded without issues, I'm trying on FF 22 without any success.
Appreciate your assistance here.

Guy

Comment: [Loader] Failed to load "chrome://Ext/content/SettingsFF.js" - Error: couldn't open library myDll.dll
<rest of the stack here>

Comment: That could also mean that it didn't find the dll.

Comment: As I mentioned, there is no path issues, since other dlls from the same folder are loaded successfully. even writing the full path doesn't help. BTW, I have tried simple win32 application LoadLibrary() worked fine.

Comment: Debugging using a real debugger might help. Related: See [Using the Mozilla symbol server](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_the_Mozilla_symbol_server). Or at the very least have a log at a [ProcessMonitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because I had “C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin” in my PATH environment. Don't know why it is related. But I'll explore it further.

Comment: Probably the loader was breaking when it encountered a space character in the PATH variable.

Answer (score 0):

Since it was working before, my guess is [ASLR enforcement](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/toolkit/xre/nsWindowsDllBlocklist.cpp#182) on Vista and later. IIRC, the whole `LoadLibrary()` function is hooked to prevent loading non-ASLR DLLs at runtime.

Try to build your DLL with [`/DYNAMICBASE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384887.aspx).

If it is not that, than the likely reason is that your DLL cannot be found. Try to use absolute paths and make sure the path is actually correct.

Comment: I'll try your 1st option, thanks. Regarding the path it is definitely not the issue.